# Why I cant iterate the the variable **element** in my forEach loop. *It says Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined*

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

Why I cant iterate the the variable **element** in my forEach loop. *It says Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined*

```
    const board = document.getElementById("board");
    const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    createELementOverArray();
    function createELementOverArray() {
      array.forEach((value) => {
        const element = document.createElement("div");
        board.appendChild(element);
        console.log(element);
      });
    }
```

I EXPECTED TO BE LIKE THIS

```
 <div id="board">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Why I cant iterate the the variable **element** in my forEach loop. *It says Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined*

Comment: Can you please share your code that is using the `forEach` loop?

Comment: You may reveal your entire code to make it easier to grasp.

Comment: I already edited it please see my updated post

Comment: The code that you've provided, will not produce the error that you've mentioned.

Comment: It works just fine when I run it. Did you have a typo somewhere maybe?

Comment: IT WORKS FINE NOW THANK YOU ALL FOR HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the error coming from this line

```js
      board.appendChild(element);
```

In fact you are defining 'board' but is board in your document?
Check the snippet, div board is in the HTML.
I've also added the line to add the class in javascript

```js
const board = document.getElementById("board");
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
createELementOverArray();

function createELementOverArray() {
  array.forEach((value) => {
    const element = document.createElement("div");
    element.classList.add('element');
    board.appendChild(element);
    console.log(element);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
</div>
```